# Eclipse doesn't report errors until runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was trying to do some messy tricks to carry in an `IMarker` a `ProblemDescriptor` object.

`ProblemDescriptor problem = new ProblemDescriptor(... my arguments...);
marker.setAttribute("PROBLEM_DESCRIPTOR", problem);`

Later on I wanted to check if the attribute is set, make use of the informations from it.

The error is not reported while developing but at runtime I get the error:

`The attribute value type is com.localhost.problems.ProblemDescription and expected is one of java.lang.String, Boolean, Integer`

Is it a special case/a bad implementation in that code or I should get used with those kinds of errors reported only at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setAttribute` method you are using is

```
public void setAttribute(String attributeName, Object value)
```

Since the second argument is `Object` no check for correctness can be done at compile time, however the Javadoc for this clearly says:

> Sets the attribute with the given name. The value must be null or an
>   instance of one of the following classes: String, Integer, or Boolean.
>   If the value is null, the attribute is considered to be undefined.
>
> The attribute value cannot be a String whose UTF encoding exceeds 65535
>   bytes. On persistent markers this limit is enforced by an assertion.

An alternative design would have been to replace this with 3 methods with a `String`, `Integer` and `Boolean` second argument but the API designers decided not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling your method correctly. That error looks like you are passing

> com.localhost.problems.ProblemDescription

To a method that is expecting something else.

... leaving out the arguments isn't helping

Comment: That's what I'm pointing out, that I pass a bad value to a method, yet the problem is not reported

Comment: Because the second parameter is accepted to be an `Object` but later on it throws an error if the value is something else than `String, Boolean, Integer`

Comment: To me, that sounds like bad programming

Comment: I think this would be caught before compile if there was casting of types. Hard to say without complete code